# Capturing subset of a string using Python's regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
>Bounded_RNA_of:1DDL:Elength : 1
```

Regex wise it can be formed this way:

```
>Bounded_RNA_of:(\w+):(\w)length : 1
```

At the end of the day what I want to extract is just `1DDL` and `E`.

But why this regex failed?

```
import re
seq=">Bounded_RNA_of:1DDL:Elength : 1"
match = re.search(r'(>Bounded_RNA_of:(\w+):(\w)length : 1)',seq)
print match.group()

# prints this:
# >Bounded_RNA_of:1DDL:Elength : 1
```

What's the way to do it?

Comment: Use `match.group(1)` and `match.group(2)` instead. `.group()` returns the whole match (`.group()` == `.group(0)`).

Comment: I tried, doesn't work.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It prints the same result `>Bounded_RNA_of:1DDL:Elength : 1`

Comment: That's most likely because for some reason, you wrapped the whole thing in a capturing group, throwing off Jerry's numbering. Remove the outer parentheses on the regex.

Comment: `group()` [returns the whole match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), not a list of capturing groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the global catching parenthesis, you should catch only the two needed elements.

```
import re
seq=">Bounded_RNA_of:1DDL:Elength : 1"
match = re.search(r'>Bounded_RNA_of:(\w+):(\w)length : 1',seq)
print match.group(1), match.group(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply print:

```
print match.group(2)
print match.group(3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1DDL
E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> match = re.search(r'>Bounded_RNA_of:(\w+):(\w)length : 1',seq)
>>> print match.group(1,2)
('1DDL', 'E')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use parenthesis in:

```
match = re.search(r'(>Bounded_RNA_of:(\w+):(\w)length : 1)',seq)
```

It should be:

```
match = re.search(r'>Bounded_RNA_of:(\w+):(\w)length : 1',seq)
```

And then you can extract 1DDL and E with:

```
print match.group(1)
print match.group(2)
```

EDIT:
If you want to keep this parenthesis you can extract info with:

```
print match.group(2)
print match.group(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered, but I'd like to suggest a more precise regex for the task:

```
import re
subject = ">Bounded_RNA_of:1DDL:Elength : 1"
match = re.search(r">\w+:([^:]+):(\w)", subject)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
    print match.group(2)
```

**Regex Explanation**

- The `>` serves as an anchor that helps the engine know we are looking in the right place. It helps prevent backtracking later.
- The `\w+:` matches what comes before the first colon `:`
- The `([^:]+)` captures any chars that are not a `:` to Group 1.
- Then we match the second `:`
- `(\w)` captures the remaining character to Group 2.